# mysql query to select record less than the date from another table?

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble with my query that will get the idno from another table and evaluate if the rdt_date  is less than the dt_date. some of the result from my query have duplicate records.  below are sample table and data with my query . Thank you in advance.

```
 create table sampleInspect (idno varchar(50), rdt_date datetime);
 insert into sampleInspect values ('ABCDE5B12AG33335281486','2021-06-03 05:51:15'),
 ('ABCDE5B12AG33335281486','2021-10-18 14:20:35'),
 ('1111111890123461281388','2021-05-10 23:33:35'),
 ('1111111890123461281388','2021-10-13 21:56:38'),
 ('2222222890123461281384','2021-10-13 19:25:28'),
 ('2222222890123461281384','2021-04-26 17:38:13'),
 ('7222222890123461281387','2021-05-10 00:47:00'),
 ('7222222890123461281387','2021-08-07 00:41:10'),
 ('3222222890123461281389','2021-08-30 09:07:57'),
 ('3222222890123461281389','2021-06-05 05:59:24'),
 ('32222228901234612813AA','2021-08-10 01:51:24'),
 ('32222228901234612813BB','2021-10-10 02:51:24'),
 ('32222228901234612813BB','2021-08-10 09:51:24');

 create table sampleRec (idno varchar(50), dt_date datetime);
 insert into sampleRec values ('ABCDE5B12AG33335281486','2021-10-05 01:17:13'),
 ('ABCDE5B12AG33335281486','2021-04-13 04:54:06'),
 ('1111111890123461281388','2021-09-28 00:29:25'),
 ('1111111890123461281388','2021-02-09 09:14:25'),
 ('2222222890123461281384','2021-09-15 07:11:20'),
 ('2222222890123461281384','2021-02-18 09:47:20')    , 
 ('2222222890123461281384','2019-12-02 06:45:38'),

 ('7222222890123461281387','2021-07-09 09:03:06'),
 ('7222222890123461281387','2021-03-22 00:42:43') ,
 ('7222222890123461281387','2020-10-05 00:19:08') ,
 ('7222222890123461281387','2019-12-16 01:33:46'), 

 ('3222222890123461281389','2021-10-12 03:18:27') ,  
 ('3222222890123461281389','2021-08-11 01:11:31'), 
 ('3222222890123461281389','2021-05-03 07:03:45') ,
 ('3222222890123461281389','2020-12-10 00:11:54') ,
 ('3222222890123461281389','2020-08-11 03:47:54'),

 ('32222228901234612813AA','2021-09-10 01:51:24'),
 ('32222228901234612813BB','2021-11-10 02:51:24'),
 ('32222228901234612813BB','2021-07-10 09:51:24')

 ;

select r.dt_date, r.idno as idno2, i.idno, i.rdt_date
from  sampleInspect i
    inner join sampleRec r on r.idno = i.idno 
        and i.rdt_date < r.dt_date
where i.rdt_date between '2021-1-1' and '2021-11-17'
```

Comment: 'some of the result from my query have duplicate records.' - looks correct what do you want to happen?

Comment: please share expected result too